# How do I find such a limit: $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^{\sin x} \sqrt{\tan t} \ dt}{\int_0^{\tan x} \sqrt{\sin t} \ dt}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis, trigonometry

How do I find the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^{\sin x} \sqrt{\tan t} \,\mathrm dt}{\int_0^{\tan x} \sqrt{\sin t} \,\mathrm dt}?
$$

The functions in numerator and denominator are a mirror image to each other. That's why I believe it is possible to merge them together under the limit. However, I know that I can go with the limit "under the integral" and I'm not sure how to merge those 2 integrals.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: anything with a $\tan x$ as $x\to\infty$ like in the denominator is undefined

Comment: The limit shouldn't exist. The function has period $2\pi$. Also, you probably shouldn't use $x$ for the integrated; it is confusing.

Comment: When $\sin x<0$ then $\tan t$ is negative between $\sin x$ and $0,$ and thus $\sqrt{\tan x}$ is undefined.

Comment: Basically, this problem is a mess.

Comment: If the upper (or lower) bound of the integral is something depending on $x$ it is cleaner to use a different variable (e.g., y) as the variable of integration.

Comment: @mathbb : As Thomas Andrews said, integrands are not defined for certain values $t$, so is it $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\int_0^{\sin x} \sqrt{|\tan t|} \ dt}{\int_0^{\tan x} \sqrt{|\sin t|} \ dt}$ ?

Comment: @mathbb Did you find this problem in a book or somewhere? It will be nice if you add how you got to know about this limit.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not $x \to 0$ ? It would make much more sense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Sorry for my previous (deleted) comment. I thought it was for $x\to 0$

Comment: @Infinity_hunter. And if we use what you wrote, the result would be oscillating between $-1$ and $+1$. I am almost sure that the problem is for $x\to 0$

Comment: Yeah, the problem is $x \to 0$, sorry guys, my bad.

Comment: And the variable $x$ in the limit and the endpoints of integration shouldn't be the same as the variable $x$ in the integrand and the $dx$. That being said, do you know what a "$\frac00$ indeterminate form" is? how to check if a particular limit is of that form? what you can do to evaluate such limits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand the question as follows:
Determine the limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^{\sin x} \sqrt{|\tan \xi|}d\xi}{\int_0^{\tan x} \sqrt{|\sin \xi|}d\xi}. $$
Let $f(x) = \int_0^{\sin x} \sqrt{|\tan \xi|}d\xi$ and $g(x) = \int_0^{\tan x} \sqrt{|\sin \xi|}d\xi$. Observe that
$$1) \ f'(x)=\cos(x)\sqrt{|\tan (\sin x)|}, \ \mathrm{and} \ g'(x) = \frac{1}{\cos^2x}\sqrt{|\sin(\tan x)|}$$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Note that we have the following Taylor expansions around $x=0:$
$$2) \ \tan(\sin x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^3), \ \ \sin(\tan x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^3). $$

Using 1) and 2), it follows that we have the limit
$$3) \ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos^3(x)\sqrt{x+\mathcal{O}(x^3)}}{\sqrt{x+\mathcal{O}(x^3)}}= 1.$$
We also note that
$$4) \ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=0.$$

By l'Hôpital's rule, it now follows from 3) and 4) that
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^{\sin x} \sqrt{|\tan \xi|}d\xi}{\int_0^{\tan x} \sqrt{|\sin \xi|}d\xi} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=1. $$

Comment: Oh, thank you, I will check in a moment if I understand everything and probably ask some questions.

Comment: @mathbb Ok, great! If you think my post answered your question, please consider "accepting" it.

Answer (score 0):

Since:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\underbrace{\int\limits_0^{\sin x}\sqrt{\tan t}\,\mathrm dt}_{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\underbrace{\int\limits_0^{\tan x}\sqrt{\sin t}\,\mathrm dt}_{g(x)}=0$$
We can use L'Hopital's rule and say that:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
Now by FTC we get that:
$$f'(x)=\left.\sqrt{\tan t}\right|_{t=0}^{\sin x}=\cos x\sqrt{\tan(\sin x)}$$
similarly:
$$g'(x)=\sec^2 x\sqrt{\sin(\tan x)}$$

---

If we define:
$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
It follows that:
$$L^2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(\sin x)}{\sin(\tan x)}$$

---

Looking at both functions, you will see that around zero:
$$\tan(\sin x)\sim\sin(\tan x)\sim x$$ and so we are left with:
$$L^2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos^2x}{\sec^4x}=\lim_{x\to0}\cos^2x=1$$